# Change class and css , with jQuery , of a flaticon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the situation

```
<div id="idDiv">
    <span class="flaticon-edit23"></span>
</div>
```

to change the css of the span i have to do this

```
#idDiv > span::before{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    color: white;
}
```

if i click on **#idDiv**, I have to change the icon of the span, and also change some parameters of the css span  (in this case, the font-size)

this works , and change correctly the icon

```
$("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13");
```

but I should change the css of the ::before selector , and i try this (and other similar combinations)

```
$("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13").find("span:before").css({"font-size":"36px"});
```

but it does not work properly

how can I do this ? thanks

[image]

### UPDATE

this don't work

```
$("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13");
$("#idDiv").find("span:before").css("font-size","36px");
```

this don't work

```
$("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13");
$("#idDiv").find("span:before").css({"font-size":"36px"});
```

this don't work

```
 .new_class{font-size: 36px; } 
 $("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13");
 $("#idDiv").find("span:first").addClass("new_class");
```

this don't work

```
 .new_class > span::before{font-size: 36px; } 
 $("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13");
 $("#idDiv").find("span:first").addClass("new_class");
```

Comment: $("#item").removeClass(); = remove all class of the #item

Comment: create another class same as span::before and addClass to it.

Comment: @Yatin Mistry yes is a possible solution

Comment: this will definitely work. try and let me know.

Comment: make it in separate lines first remove then add and then change font

Comment: @Yatin Mistry , your solution does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think [pseudo elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) can be selected and modified as you are trying to do here.

What you can instead do is to have two different pseudo elements defined and either of them would get applied based on the span's CSS class.

e.g.

```
#idDiv > span.flaticon-edit23::before{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    color: white;
}

#idDiv > span.flaticon-floppy13::before{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    color: white;
}
```

and then, only changing the CSS class of the span

```
$("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13");
```

should be sufficient..

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13");
$("#idDiv").find("span:before").css("font-size":"36px");
```

Also

```
if (!$('.your class').val()) {
            $('#idDiv').val("flaticon-floppy13");
        } else {
            $('#idDiv').val("");
        }
```

or just remove {} but its better to separate the functions. I don't think they work together.

Comment: $("#idDiv").find("span:first").removeClass().addClass("flaticon-floppy13").find("span:before").css("font-size:36px"); try this

Comment: your second solution generates an error, so it does not work . also putting , in place of : (here css("font-size:36px") )

Comment: this is correct : css("font-size, 36px") , this NO : css("font-size: 36px")

Comment: @WhiteLine  your correct is **not correct**, must be `.css("fontSize", "36px")`

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the same like this?

```
 .new_class{font-size: 36px !important; } 

$("#idDiv").find("span:first").addClass("new_class");
```

Comment: what error are you getting in console? is  it the same as you want?